# Logic App to Synchronize SharePoint Library with Blob storage

Tags: sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a SharePoint Library that includes a number of folders, sub-folders and files. The directory structure is may change over time. The goal is to create a LogicApp which triggers whenever a file in the library is created, modified or deleted and creates, modifies or deletes the file in a blob container using the same directory structure. Is this possible without nested loops, i.e. listing all folders, listing all sub-folders, listing all files?

Answer (score 1):

For now sharepoint only supports the `When a file is created or modified (properties only)` or `When a file is deleted` not the `When a file is created or modified or deleted`. So if you want to implement your requirements, you have to create two logic apps. The below is a sample one about `When a file is created or modified` and create the blob with new file.

[image]

If just modify  the file the blob will replace it with new content so this flow is OK. About when file is deleted you could refer to the picture above, change the trigger, no get content, delete the with with the trigger information.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: This works for when a file is created or modified, but "when a file is deleted", returns a DeletedItemList which does not contain the path of where the file was. I don't see how looping can be avoided to find the corresponding file in the blob storage. I have a situation where files with the same name in different directories.

Comment: Sorry I don't have right to test this trigger. And I check the trigger doc, the return body only include the filename, so maybe you could provide a screenshot about the dynamic contents the connection provides, or you could set the folder in the trigger connection, however this would be a little trouble if there are many folders.

Comment: For now looks in logic app no much better ways to solve it. If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer. Thanks!